# angular 1.3 bind once doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple code and I don't know why when I'm typing in the input text it updates the two `<h1>` instead of only the second?

```
<h1>{{::person.name}}</h1>
<h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="person.name"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened to us as well, AngularJS 1.3's bind-once does not work when Batarang extension is enabled.
Disable Batarang and everything will be OK

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are using angular 1.3 version. Please see working sample below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.person = {
    name: "Jack"
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">

      <h1>{{::person.name}}</h1>
      <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
      <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I know its so weird here its working and on my local computer dont work

Comment: @anguLaravel have you checked what version of angular are you using ?

Comment: Yes sure this is why i dont know why it doesnt work for the first place

Comment: So this is a local issue only? Try `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/...."` instead.

Comment: Not works even with bower version. Im working with browserify maybe some conflict with that??

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Try to disable AngularJS Chrome extension. I disabled mine and bind once started to work.