# Angular 1.3 one-way binding isn't working

Tags: angularjs

I have a large scale Angular app.  I'm migrating from 1.2 to 1.3 and in the process, migrating from bindonce to Angular 1.3's native one-way binding.  The problem is that for whatever reason, the watcher's never de-register as they should with the "value stabilization algorithm", https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#value-stabilization-algorithm.

Something as simple as `{{::var1}}` retains its watcher.  It results in the same total watcher count as `{{var1}`.  However, `<span bindonce="var1" bo-text="var1"></span`> works great.

Unfortunately, I can not replicate this in a plnkr.  I ensured my app is running Angular 1.3.14.  Any reason why the watcher would not de-register?  I suspect it has to do with a combination of other modules that the app using but not sure how to confirm.

Comment: Is that value initially `undefined`? If the expression is `undefined`, then the watcher associated with that expression's watcher will be "unfulfilled" and won't be de-registered.

Comment: No, that value should immediately have a value.  I'm just doing $scope.var1 = "test" in my controller and then displaying it in the UI using the three bind methods.  Only bindonce actually removes the watcher.  In plnkr using a similar example, Angular 1.3's does remove the watcher so something must be different with my codebase.  I am certain I'm using Angular 1.3 in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being the batarang extension as noted in the following references.

[angular 1.3 bind once doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613909/angular-1-3-bind-once-dont-work?rq=1)

https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/issues/209